# Pass by reference in a soap call (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, soap

I'm attempting to make a SOAP call in objective-C to a web service that apparently requires a parameter to be passed by reference (I think). I don't have access to the web service itself, I'm only tasked to work with it. I've been given examples in C# to work with the problem, which are essentially:

```
var response = ServiceClient.Method(out parameter1, parameter2;
```

In C# theres conveniently that 'out' keyword but I haven't come across anything like that in ObjC. Currently I'm making soap calls like:

```
        NSMutableArray* _params = [NSMutableArray array];
        [_params addObject: [[[SoapParameter alloc] initWithValue: parameter1 forName: @"paramName"] autorelease]];
    NSString* _envelope = [Soap createEnvelope: @"Method" forNamespace: self.namespace withParameters: _params withHeaders: self.headers];

    SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"http://blahblahblah" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: [[responseType alloc] autorelease]];
    [_request send];
    return _request;
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> In C# theres conveniently that 'out' keyword but I haven't come across anything like that in ObjC.

The equivalent to **out** is to use a pointer to the variable. Define your method like this:

```
- (int) aMethodWithOutParameter:(NSString**)param {}
```

Then use it like this:

```
NSString *s;
int result = [self aMethodWithOutParameter:&s];
NSLog(@"result = %i, s = %@", result, s);
```

Note the extra `*` in the method declaration, and then `&` on the passed in variable when calling it.

Comment: Anytime you define a method that returns `void` and has a pass-by-reference parameter, you are doing it wrong.  That should simply be `-(NSString*)someMethod;`.  *There is absolutely no reason to use pass by reference in this case, nor is it needed to solve OP's problem.*

Comment: *"There is absolutely no reason to use pass by reference in this case"* — true, it's a contrived example to answer his question about the Objective-C equivalent of C#'s "out". *"nor is it needed to solve OP's problem"* — You're right that I didn't solve the whole problem, as I didn't have enough info, but I did answer the part of his request which was "how do I do return by reference in objective C?".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post code;  there is no reason or need to use pass by reference from what you have posted so far, but there also isn't enough information to give a proper answer.

This doesn't make sense, either: `[[responseType alloc] autorelease]]` as the object is not being initialized.

Reading that code, the `SoapRequest` API seems odd, too.